# PulseAudio won't work in system mode

Tags: linux, pulseaudio, buildroot

I'm using PulseAudio on my Buildroot based system. It does work when I run it the simplest way (`# pulseaudio`), but it won't run if I launch it in system mode (`# pulseaudio --system`).

Here is the output when I run `pulseaudio --system` :

```
    # pulseaudio --system
    N: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode, forcibly disabling SHM mode.
    N: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode, forcibly disabling exit idle time.
    W: [pulseaudio] caps.c: Normally all extra capabilities would be dropped now, but that's impossible because PulseAudio was built without capabilities support.
    W: [pulseaudio] main.c: OK, so you are running PA in system mode. Please note that you most likely shouldn't be doing that.
    W: [pulseaudio] main.c: If you do it nonetheless then it's your own fault if things don't work as expected.
    W: [pulseaudio] main.c: Please read http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/WhatIsWrongWithSystemWide/ for an explanation why system mode is usually a bad idea.
    W: [pulseaudio] module.c: module-detect is deprecated: Please use module-udev-detect instead of module-detect!
    E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-sink" (argument: "device_id=0"): initialization failed.
    E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-source" (argument: "device_id=0"): initialization failed.
    W: [pulseaudio] module-detect.c: failed to detect any sound hardware.
    E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-detect" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
    E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
    E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
```

Errors are marked with an `E`. I don't understand at all what can be the problem, because it perfectly works when I'm not in system mode.

I absolutely need the system mode, because the daemon mode sometimes unexpectedly exits and I must relaunch it. I want my PulseAudio stable and always running !

Do you guys have an idea of what I can do ?